# .NET web applicatrion - drag & drop button causes it to print javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, web-applications

I'm developing a .NET web application.

When buttons are dragged and dropped (not intentionally) into a text field, the javascript behind them seems to get printed in the textfield too. There seems to be no consistency in determining whether or not dragging and dropping a button into a text field will print the javascript.

Does anyone know what defines this behaviour and how it can be prevented?

Basically the javascript that drives the button is printed into the textfield (yes I guess like the href for links), for example:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderActions$LinkButtonMovePrevious','')
```

Comment: What do you mean by javascript behind them, can you post an example of what it gave for you ? you can try with the tags in the question here they would give the href part of the anchor, do you mean that ?

Comment: What browser are you using? Does this happen on other browsers too?